# upickle gives a ScalaReflectionException when writing a case class

Tags: scala, scala.js, upickle

I have a simple case class:

```
object Margin {
  def apply(top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int, left: Int): Margin = {
    Margin(Some(top), Some(right), Some(bottom), Some(left))
  }
}

case class Margin(top: Option[Int], right: Option[Int], bottom: Option[Int], left: Option[Int])
```

When calling `upickle.write` on an instance of the above class, I get the following exception:

```
scala.ScalaReflectionException: value apply encapsulates multiple     
overloaded alternatives and cannot be treated as a method. Consider 
invoking `<offending symbol>.asTerm.alternatives` and manually picking 
the required method
```

What does this error message mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above error message is a result of the `Margin` class having multiple overloaded `apply` methods. The first one is the case class constructor, and the other is in the companion object. Upickle does not know which `apply` method to use and thus throws this exception. This is a [known limitation](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2031).

One workaround is to rename the `apply` method that is in the companion object. Another is to write a [custom pickler](http://lihaoyi.github.io/upickle/#CustomPicklers).

Here is a somewhat clumsy version of a custom pickler that solved the problem:

```
object Margin {
  def create(top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int, left: Int): Margin = {
    Margin(Some(top), Some(right), Some(bottom), Some(left))
  }

  implicit val marginWriter = upickle.Writer[Margin]{
    case m =>
      Js.Obj(fields(m).map(kv => (kv._1, Js.Num(kv._2))):_*).asInstanceOf[Js.Value]
  }

  implicit val marginReader = upickle.Reader[Margin]{
    case obj: Js.Obj =>
      val map = obj.value.toMap
      Margin(map.get("top").map(_.value.asInstanceOf[Int]),
        map.get("right").map(_.value.asInstanceOf[Int]),
        map.get("bottom").map(_.value.asInstanceOf[Int]),
        map.get("left").map(_.value.asInstanceOf[Int]))
  }

  private def fields(m: Margin) = Seq(m.top.map(("top", _)), m.right.map(("right", _)), m.bottom.map(("bottom", _)),
    m.left.map(("left", _))).flatten
}
```